# Not able to run C# Program from specific network drive

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a very simple WPF program that should display a computer's name and IP address. The following is the code I use to obtain the name and IPs.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RefreshHostname();
        RefreshIp();
    }


private void RefreshHostname()
{
    ComputerNameValue.Text = Environment.MachineName;
}
private void RefreshIp()
{
    IPHostEntry host;
    string localIP = "";
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
        {
            if (localIP == "")
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                localIP = localIP + System.Environment.NewLine + ip.ToString();
            }


        }
    }
    IPValue.Text = localIP;
}
```

These are called as the WPF starts and two TextBlocks are set to it.

If I copy the EXE to my network drives mapped to H: ,I: , or S: I can run it normally.
However if I copy it to my M: Drive, it does not run. I see it launch in Task Manager, but it quickly goes away.

Comment: The issue is most likely a security policy issue.  By default, network drives are untrusted.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e4a65263-24f9-45a6-a2ad-6c26aae36075/how-to-run-net-executable-on-a-network-drive?forum=clr

Comment: So why does it work from all of them but this one? All my mapped drives are subfolders on a server share. And I have tried the CasPol to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to the seedy world of security policies in .Net.  The CLR is very fickle when it comes to CasPol.  Go out and grab: http://brandonpotter.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/code-access-security-policy-caspol-exe-gui-utility/  It will make your life with CasPol much easier.

Comment: I also suggest you try "caspol –security off" and see if it runs before you bang your head against the wall too much.

Comment: Okay, so after adding the folder of the troublesome drive and also setting the file itsself to FullTrust I am still unable to run it from this certain location. It very strange because I have the same settings on all these network drives. And it works on all others. Ugh, so silly.

Comment: now looking into a meesage i get running caspol manually from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(VS.100).aspx, seems CasPol is no longer used.

Comment: So, If I remove
    RefreshHostname();
    RefreshIp(); The program will launch, but the computername and  are blank. But it launches.

Comment: What is different about your M: drive? Is it mapped to the same server, just a different path? Or is M: mapped to a completely different server?

Comment: Same server different path. All drives are different folders on the same server.